# Match id at base path rather than under controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, catch-all

Say I have a User Model. And a route such as this:

```
http://www.mycoolapp.com/users/1
```

How can I match `http://www.mycoolapp.com/1` where 1 matches the first User, without using `/users/1`.

Do you use a catch all? How is this accomplished in rails routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Routes file will need to look something like this, assuming you already have a User resource:

```
YourApp::Application.routes.draw do
  ....
  ....
  resources :user

  get ":id" => "users#show", :as => 'root_user'
end
```

The very last line - and it **must** be last, so it doesn't override other urls in your application - manually creates a path that should work.  You can also reference it using 'root_user_path' in your code to create the links.

Answer (score 1):

**You can do this**

```
get ":id" => "users#show"
```